# Why is express.urlencoded not a function while testing with Jest?

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs

I am testing my app.js using Jest and it says `express.urlencoded` is not a function.

Im using express 4.16.4 and while I am writing test for app.js that looks somewhat like this

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(require('./routes'));
module.exports = app;
```

and my test case is:

```
jest.mock('express');
it('has a parser', () => {
        const app = require('../src/app');
        const express = require('express');
        expect(app.use).toHaveBeenCalledWith(express.urlencoded());
    });
```

This gives me an error saying: `express.urlencoded is not a function.`

I expect this test to pass because the app works perfectly fine but only inside the test it says that express.urlencoded is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually provide factory and mock module methods there, which you want to test. This would look something like this:

```
const urlencodedMock = jest.fn();
jest.mock('express', () => {
    urlencoded: urlencodedMock,
});
it('has a parser', () => {
    const app = require('../src/app');
    const express = require('express');
    expect(app.use).toHaveBeenCalledWith(urlencodedMock);
});
```

EDIT:

I am not familiar with express, but you can try something like example below. `jest.mock()` will mock express in a way that it passes `express()` and then inside the test when that part is passed, it will mock it again, to provide `json()` and `urlencoded()` functions to express.

```
jest.mock('express', () => {
    return {
        use: () => {
            return;
        }
    }
});
it('has a parser', () => {
    const jsonMock = jest.fn();
    const urlencodedMock = jest.fn();
    const app = require('../src/app');
    jest.doMock('express', () => {
        json: jsonMock,
        urlencoded: urlencodedMock,
    });
    expect(app.use).toHaveBeenCalledWith(urlencodedMock);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it gives me this.
`babel-plugin-jest-hoist: The module factory of 'jest.mock()' is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables.Invalid variable access: urlencodedMock`

Comment: As you suggested that we need to manually provide factory and mock module methods. Even if I dont provide these manually so my actual test does run with `express.json()` but it only crashes for `express.urlencoded()`. Not sure why this is so?

Comment: Even if we replace `urlencoded: jest.fn()` directly, then we'll get `express is not a function` on `const app = express();`

Comment: Looks like there are some specific things for testing express. Can you for start remove ‘const express = ...’ from test? It shouldn’t be there since express is mocked.

Comment: It's an unused variable, removed but no effect. The `express.json()` that gives `express is not a function` is not from test code but is from actual code line 2.

To fix that, your code needs to be something like: 
`jest.mock('express', () => () => { return { use: () => { return } } });`
It fixes `const app = express()` but then it says `express.json is not a function` on line # 3.

Comment: I've updated my answer with additional attempt. Hopefully it will help you get to the right solution.